# Android - pass dynamic data to onClick

Tags: android

This sounds like the other questions, but it actually is a little different. So my scenario is, I have six buttons and the user can click any of them => but I want to keep track of the ORDER by which the buttons were clicked. So here's what I did. I saved a record in SQLite and using the date, I can determine the order the buttons were clicked. Is there another way to do this?

```
public class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // I want to be able to pass data in this method.
       try {    
           v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       }
       saveClickDAO(); // has Date field to sort later
    }
```

Is there a way to actually pass data to this onClick event? I know I can add data using a parameter to the constructor here, but that would be data that is static already.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to access in the `onClick` method? If it's related to the button you can just use the `View v` to gather the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `View v` in your `onClick(View v)`, so you can use data on the `View`. `v.getId()` or `v.getTag()` will give you some view related data.

- `v.getId()` will give you the `android:id` you set in your layout xml, such as R.id.some_btn
- `v.getTag()` will give you the object you set with `v.setTag(Object o)`.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. When I setTag (dataObj), how can that dataObj contain the order for which the button was clicked?

Comment: @ibaralf Maybe you can pass a `Date` as the dataObj.